# How do I subtract the address of a pointer from another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a HW assignment to write malloc in C.  For part of the whole algorithm of freeing a pointer, I need to subtract the address of the heap we are using to then do some bit manipulation.  So I have the following two declarations that are later defined in my program.

```
void* heap;  
 metadata_t* ptr; //always < 8kb from heap
```

My goal is to take the address of heap and subtract it from ptr because the bit manipulation that I'm doing only works if the left most bit is a zero. Everything I've tried so far has resulted in errors. Does anyone know how to do what I'm trying?

Comment: "in C", so why the C++ tag?

Comment: This is a completely unintelligible question. I have no idea what you are talking about. There is not even any code illustrating the problem or the supposed "errors". Damnit Jim, I am a doctor not a mind reader.

Comment: `(intptr_t)ptr2 - (intptr_t)ptr1`?

Comment: @vsoftco actually `(metadata_t*)heap`

Comment: @Nawaz: No, you don't have to convert pointers to integers; just do pointer arithmetic directly. (I've worked on systems where the `intptr_t` conversion would cause incorrect results.)

Comment: Generally in C: (char*)p - (char*)base = offset_in_bytes

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually it is no problem whatsoever to subtract two pointers and store the result in an `int` (on a64 bit machine you probably want to use e.g. a long long int.

Comment: What do you mean by "the address of a pointer"? Do you mean the address of a pointer object, or the address to which it points? If you want the difference in bytes, convert both pointers to `char*` and subtrace. Be aware that the language doesn't define the behavior unless both pointers point into, or just past the end of, the same (array) object -- but if you're implementing `malloc` you're almost certainly going to have to depend on non-portable behavior anyway.

Comment: Just note that result of pointer and pointer subtraction is `ptfdiff_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that subtraction "just works", and returns an integer-type result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char string[] = "This is a test string";
    char *a = string+8;
    char *b = string+10;
    long x = b-a;

    printf("Hello, World! a and b are %ld bytes apart\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Longer answer - if you're going to do **a lot** of arithmetic, cast the pointers to an appropriately-large integer type, do the arithmetic, then cast them back to a pointer. This is inherently unportable, but you're writing malloc, so portability is probably not high on the list of concerns.

Things can get a bit tricky, because you'll likely want an unsigned integer type to preserve all of the bits of the pointer, but doing arithmetic on unsigned types in C can be annoying.

Comment: (intptr_t)ptr2 - (intptr_t)ptr1 = sizeof(*ptr1) * (ptr1 - ptr2)